# iOS "Print" or "Send" icon

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, airprint

Where can I get that standard "Send" or "Print" icon that I'm "supposed" to use for AirPrint printing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the default SystemAction bar button item as you can see below:

```
UIBarButtonItem *printBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction 
                                                     target:self 
                                                     action:@selector(handlePrintTapped)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:printBarButtonItem animated:TRUE];
```